# JFreeChart histogram with varying bin sizes

Tags: scala, jfreechart, histogram

How would I go about creating a histogram plot with JFreeChart, where the bins are exponentially growing, e.g. having intervals `[0, 0.1)`, `[0.1, 0.2)`, `[0.2, 0.4)`, `[0.4, 0.8)` etc.

There is a `HistogramBin` class but it only seems to be used by `HistogramDataset`, which in turn doesn't seem to support varying bin sizes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can use a regular XY bar chart with pre-binning. Here is an example using [scala-chart](https://github.com/wookietreiber/scala-chart) and a few extra [numeric operations](https://github.com/Sciss/Numbers):

```
import de.sciss.numbers.Implicits._
import scalax.chart.{ChartFactories, Charting}
import Charting._

def mkHisto(durations: Seq[Double]): Chart[_] = {
  // ..., -0.54, -0.18, -0.06, +0.06, +0.18, +0.54, ....
  def bin(dur: Double) =
    ((dur.abs / 0.06).log / 3.log + 1).toInt.clip(0, 10) * dur.signum

  val binned  = durations.map(bin).counted.toSeq.sortBy(_._1)
  val ds      = binned.toXYSeriesCollection()
  val ch      = ChartFactories.XYBarChart(ds,
    domainAxisLabel = "bin", rangeAxisLabel = "frequency", legend = false)
  ChartFactories.XYBarChart(ds)
}  

implicit class RichIterable[A, CC[~] <: Iterable[~]](it: CC[A]) {
  def counted: Map[A, Int] = (Map.empty[A, Int].withDefaultValue(0) /: it)((m, e) => 
    m.updated(e, m(e) + 1))
}
```

Without further plot/renderer customisation, this looks like this, given particular input data:

[image]

---

Test data:

```
val x = Vector(22.23312925170068, 15.460136054421769, 10.453968253968254, 0.7362131519274376, 1.9141043083900227, -80.39263038548752, 5.153378684807256, 44.46625850340136, -0.2944897959183673, -192.94580498866213, 7.566507936507937, -295.0935827664399, -11.909251700680272, -16.433492063492064, -15.60591836734694, 23.64532879818594, -22.69950113378685, 108.23530612244897, 2.352925170068027, 27.058820861678004, -22.352925170068026, -4.705873015873016, -4.5397278911564625, -1.7646938775510204, 81.76471655328798, -6.470589569160998, 30.967732426303854, 13.76344671201814, 2.867392290249433, 26.379931972789116, -17.51825396825397, 23.746961451247167, -30.410430839002267, -13.722630385487529, -146.28009070294786, -130.3674603174603, 1.4976643990929706, 0.936031746031746, 2.3244444444444445, -61.95258503401361, -50.051859410430836, -47.48528344671202, -69.55430839002267, -119.96390022675737, -3.2929931972789115, -3.2929931972789115, -5.447936507936508, -18.498798185941045, -18.78934240362812, 18.498798185941045, 58.11138321995465, 33.510884353741496, 44.55206349206349, 30.02421768707483, -113.5108843537415, 27.40918367346939, -1.1934920634920634, -120.73696145124717, 5.617437641723356, 5.617437641723356, 3.8740816326530614, 3.8740816326530614, -126.38659863945578, 17.820839002267572, 18.5956462585034, -26.731224489795917, -16.920226757369615, -52.91142857142857, -24.26716553287982, 7.346938775510204, -11.354353741496599, -11.13172335600907, -1.7810657596371882, -0.7305215419501134, -117.56074829931973, -2.240249433106576, 0.12176870748299319, -113.44839002267574, -13.12498866213152, -86.2028798185941, -5.47891156462585, -2.240249433106576, -0.09741496598639456, -1.168843537414966, -10.227256235827664, -4.577936507936508, -51.70156462585034, -0.4870068027210884, -0.7548752834467121, -5.405827664399093, 6.185079365079365, -29.959365079365078, -1.6558503401360545, -7.183424036281179, -1.0714285714285714, -16.747414965986394, -2.897732426303855, -0.9740362811791383, -63.77263038548753, -8.098163265306123, -18.388820861678006, -6.699387755102041, 17.079750566893424, 33.644172335600906, -37.55328798185941, -6.772993197278912, 28.564421768707483, -3.7546031746031745, -14.47281179138322, -5.963197278911565, 26.282222222222224, 16.35233560090703, 11.564761904761905, 12.0, 9.015555555555556, -13.994920634920636, -4.041451247165533, -4.103628117913832, -9.994149659863945, -3.35750566893424, -0.7461224489795918, -0.6839455782312925, -21.39922902494331, -1.7409297052154196, -4.414512471655329, -2.4248526077097505, -5.4714965986394555, -32.42954648526077, -2.549206349206349, 11.626938775510204, -18.03108843537415, -7.150272108843537, 2.7357596371882087, -0.06217687074829932, 0.18653061224489795, -2.3005215419501135, -39.17097505668934, -0.3730612244897959, 0.6217687074829932, 1.181360544217687, 1.1191836734693879, 0.13990929705215419, 0.09326530612244897, 0.09326530612244897, 0.21759637188208616, 0.1554421768707483, 0.1554421768707483, 46.169160997732426, 1.1940136054421768, 60.49750566893424, 6.965192743764172, -5.572154195011338, 19.041315192743763, 109.88430839002268, 54.30657596371882, -5.252517006802721, 202.51149659863947, 4.96172335600907, -50.526326530612245, -1.1271655328798187, -10.404625850340135, -31.21387755102041, -1.7774603174603174, -3.8150340136054424, -4.638730158730159, -86.35839002267574, -14.132947845804988, 6.936417233560091, -107.85619047619048, 0.8880498866213152, -9.766190476190475, 3.8756009070294786, 65.26315192743765, -283.5050793650794, -0.5741723356009071, -0.1953061224489796, 0.5524943310657596, -37.47823129251701, -21.6, -6.4, -19.771428571428572, -100.0, -22.514285714285716, 18.742857142857144, -16.9443537414966, -2.0285714285714285, 13.057142857142857, -5.457142857142857, -15.342857142857143, 11.257142857142858, -15.480544217687076, -8.657142857142857, 1.7428571428571429, 3.914285714285714, 4.857142857142857, -8.485714285714286, 0.8857142857142857, -0.7714285714285715, -0.6857142857142857, 92.43299319727892, -5.503673469387755, -12.972993197278912, -8.255510204081633, -181.06972789115648, -180.77814058956915, -25.25798185941043, -25.25798185941043, -30.27027210884354, -31.449637188208616, -13.759229024943311, -11.007392290249433, -2.358730158730159, -1.2226757369614512, 9.106235827664399, -307.3968934240363, 2.0236054421768706, -10.522766439909297, -9.409773242630385, -8.600340136054422, -8.39798185941043, -7.48734693877551, 44.11467120181406, 66.37437641723356, 58.988185941043085, 92.58009070294784, 62.7318820861678, -82.63780045351474, -76.79596371882086, -65.26138321995465, -103.40639455782313, -139.21777777777777, 77.70657596371882, 93.18718820861677, 93.18716553287982, -31.044104308390022, 33.69308390022676, -32.37773242630386, 50.084331065759635, 48.971337868480724, -5.261383219954649, -19.189886621315193, 1.9224263038548752, 0.8094557823129251, -1.5177097505668935, -1.6188888888888888, -0.6078911564625851, 0.089297052154195, -21.281791383219954, -2.2843990929705216, -1.9088662131519274, 1.3155555555555556, -2.734308390022676, -26.930340136054422, 135.16766439909298, -112.22884353741496, 21.358548752834466, -31.16079365079365, -16.921768707482993, 30.02580498866213, -33.637142857142855, -21.874467120181407, -0.5675056689342404, 90.3869387755102, -35.49442176870748, -3.0954421768707485, 3.0954421768707485, -15.033968253968254, -0.6792290249433106, 0.9962131519274376, 14.671700680272108, -6.520748299319728, 0.8603854875283447, 4.709433106575964, 7.290566893424036, -25.17736961451247, -28.8, -3.079251700680272, -0.9962358276643991, 145.2679365079365, -113.0264172335601, 41.660385487528345, -1.0868027210884355, -119.54716553287982, 22.0981179138322, -279.7477551020408, -47.021519274376416, 3.227641723356009, 3.006802721088435, -0.9173242630385487, 1.2910430839002267, -153.88185941043085, 1.0074603174603174, 2.0149433106575962, -1.5671655328798186, 0.5596825396825397, -154.90068027210884, -34.02984126984127, -34.25371882086168, -41.082086167800455, -37.16417233560091, -0.11192743764172336, -37.879886621315194, -24.738798185941043, -2.4626757369614514, -19.25374149659864, -24.40299319727891, -6.380589569160998, -0.27984126984126984, -0.3078231292517007, -0.13990929705215419, -0.13990929705215419, -1.063424036281179, -1.7910430839002267, -0.12594104308390022, 0.30784580498866215, -0.09938775510204081, -0.10480725623582766, -0.10480725623582766, -39.196507936507935, 18.213061224489795, 13.785895691609978, -6.266326530612245, -0.8355102040816327, 14.830272108843538, -2.786077097505669, -9.43718820861678, 0.23512471655328798, 0.2821315192743764, -26.80249433106576, 0.721655328798186, -84.25963718820861, 27.050362811791384, 27.050362811791384)
```

Test:

```
mkHisto(x).show()
```

---

What remains to be done is customising x-axis labelling. The following addition to `mkHisto` changes colours and puts the proper x-axis labels:

```
import java.awt.Color
import org.jfree.chart.axis.{NumberTickUnit, NumberAxis}
import org.jfree.chart.plot.ValueMarker
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.{StandardXYBarPainter, XYBarRenderer}

def lim(idx: Int) = 
  if (idx == 0) 0.0 else ((idx.abs - 1) * 3.log).exp * 0.06 * idx.signum

val plot = ch.plot
plot.getRenderer.asInstanceOf[XYBarRenderer].setBarPainter(new StandardXYBarPainter())
plot.addDomainMarker(new ValueMarker(0))
plot.setBackgroundPaint           (Color.white    )
plot.setDomainGridlinePaint       (Color.lightGray)
plot.setRangeGridlinePaint        (Color.lightGray)
plot.getRenderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.darkGray )
val xAxis = plot.getDomainAxis.asInstanceOf[NumberAxis]
xAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(1) {
  override def valueToString(bin: Double) = {
    val sig = if (bin < 0) "\u2212" else if (bin > 0) "+" else ""
    f"""$sig${lim(bin.toInt).abs}%1.2f""""
  }
})
xAxis.setVerticalTickLabels(true)
val yAxis = plot.getRangeAxis
yAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits())
```

Final result:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't a histogram by definition represent data by area, so the buckets need to be the appropriate length on the x-axis? (I could  be wrong)

Comment: When talking about magnitudes such as time spans or frequencies, logarithmic scales are more appropriate. What the x-axis labels denote is each bin's upper interval margin. Think of the x-axis as twice logarithmic (left half is negative durations, right half is positive durations). BTW the unit is redundant ([s] versus ")